# How to append elements from input to empty list in python

Tags: python

I want to make a program where an empty list is populated by an input from the user. How do I do that?

**My python code:**

```py
def passanger_list(passangerInput, pp): 
    pp = ["passangers:"]
    passangerInput = input("what is your passanger name?")   
    if passangerInput:
        pp.append()
    
    print(passanger_list)
```

Comment: sorry for the bad indentation, for some reason the question did not translate well in the comment.

Comment: What is your question? You should edit you post to ask something specific about your code - i.e. is it not working and if so what's actually produced and what do you want it to produce?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think it is better to use a list of dictionaries instead of a list.

Instead of this:

```
    pp = ["passangers:"]
    passangerInput = input("what is your passanger name?")   
    if passangerInput:
        pp.append()

print(passanger_list)
```

I would do:

```
passenger_list = []

def add_passenger(passenger_name): 
    if passanger_name:
        passenger_list.append({"name":passenger_name})

add_passenger("bob")
print(passanger_list)
```

This way you can store multiple passengers and can even add other key-value pairs like seat number or class etc.

The way you are doing it will make it harder to retrieve information.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this example helped the best. Good luck in your work!

Comment: No problem. I don't know why someone disliked my suggestion XD. It is better than most of the suggestions here lol.

Answer (score 1):

Do it this way

```
''' You dont need to send pp and passengerInput as parameters for this function because, they're values are being initialized only when the passenger_list() is called. ''' 
def passenger_list(): 
    ''' It would be better for you to avoid having the passengers text inside. If you really want the values as passenger: "name of passenger", you can use a dictionary. I will add code for that as well.'''
    pp = []
    passengerInput = input("what is your passanger name?")   
    if passengerInput:
        pp.append(passengerInput)
    print(pp)
    
    # This statement is crucial so that the value is passed back to the code that is calling it.
    return pp
```

In this case, after calling `passenger_list()`, your output will look like `["Ram", "Shyam", "Sita"]`.

For output of the form - `{"Passengers":["Ram","Shyam","Sita]}`, please refer the code below.

```
def passenger_list(): 
    
    pp = {"Passengers":[]}
    passengerInput = input("what is your passanger name?")   
    if passengerInput:
        pp["Passengers"].append(passengerInput)
    print(pp)
    # You can access the list using pp["Passenggers"]
    print(pp["Passengers"]) # Output is ["Ram", "Shyam", "Sita"]  
    
    return pp
```

Read more about Python dictionaries [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you:

```
def passanger_list(passangerInput, pp): 
    if passangerInput:
        pp.append(passangerInput)
    return pp

pp = []
pp = passanger_list(
    input("what is your passanger name?"),
    pp
)

print("passangers:", pp)
```

Also, you might want to spell it "passengers" instead of "passangers".

Comment: This makes `pp`  `['some name', []]` instead of `['some name']`.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def passanger_list(): 
    pp = ["passangers:"]
    passangerInput = input("what is your passanger name?")   
    if passangerInput:
        pp.append(passangerInput)
    return pp

print(passanger_list())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you define `pp = ["passangers:"]` why do you want to get input for your function?

```
global pp 
pp= {"passengers":[]}

def passanger_list(): 
    passangerInput = input("what is your passanger name?")
    
    pp["passengers"].append(passangerInput) 
   

    return pp

>>> passanger_list()
```